# Creating an updating gallery

Tags: php, gallery, last-modified

I'm looking for this to work with video but it could equally work with photos and other multimedia. I'm wanting to create a page with various sections each held in their own div. I then will have a folder where I will upload a still from the video, the video itself and the title and description in different files. I then want each div to go into this folder and select the last uploaded files and display them. You will then be able to click on the div and it will open up another page with the title, description and video.
I have been searching around but think that my request is too specific to try and find an answer.
I'm guessing that I will need to use php somewhere along the way such as selecting the folder and getting the last uploaded files but am unsure what else and even how to build everything else.
I'd be grateful of any information you could give.

Comment: You need a discussion forum, or to hire a programmer. StackOverflow is a place to get specific answer to specific programming questions. If you really don't even know where to start, start with the PHP manual at http://www.php.net. If you start skimming it, you'll come across all the functions you need.

Comment: Do you have any programming experience in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach to list images from a gallery by their modification time:

```
$images = glob("gallery/*.jpeg");
$images = array_combine($images, $images);
$images = array_map("filemtime", $images);
arsort($images);
print_r(array_keys($images));
```

Though you would need some more code to pretty print that.

If you are actually looking for code or some ready-made script, then there's ["PHP Gallery"](http://gallery.menalto.com/) I think.

Comment: How can I then make another div get the 2nd last uploaded image and also how do I make the image actually display on the web page from the code you have given as my knowledge of php is restricted.

Comment: @Jordan: I'm not coding for you, nor do I provide language tutoring via comments. Use an existing script.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to offend you!

Comment: @Jordan: Me neither. You'll have to find an existing solution if you can't program. Stackoverflow is strictly for coding questions.